# Create new record of a nested resource from the index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 resources which are nested:

```
  resources :clientes do
    resources :projects
  end
```

I need 2 buttons on my index page, one for creating Clients and the other one to create projects.

```
<%= link_to "Nuevo Cliente", new_cliente_path %>
<%= link_to "Nuevo Projecto", new_cliente_project_path() %>
```

The problem:
When clicking on new project, the **new_cliente_project_path** needs the client id passed in a parameter.

I still don't have that parameter because the new project to create has no client assigned still.

I would like to have the project's client selected from the new project form.

How can I proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have an un-nested resource, something like:

```
resources :clientes do
  resources :projects, except: [:new, :create]
end

resources :projects, only: [:new, :create]
```

Which will give you (notice that your `new_projects` and `projects` paths will no longer require `cliente_id`):

```
    cliente_projects GET    /clientes/:cliente_id/projects(.:format)              projects#index
edit_cliente_project GET    /clientes/:cliente_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format)     projects#edit
     cliente_project GET    /clientes/:cliente_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#show
                     PATCH  /clientes/:cliente_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#update
                     PUT    /clientes/:cliente_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#update
                     DELETE /clientes/:cliente_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#destroy
            clientes GET    /clientes(.:format)                                   clientes#index
                     POST   /clientes(.:format)                                   clientes#create
         new_cliente GET    /clientes/new(.:format)                               clientes#new
        edit_cliente GET    /clientes/:id/edit(.:format)                          clientes#edit
             cliente GET    /clientes/:id(.:format)                               clientes#show
                     PATCH  /clientes/:id(.:format)                               clientes#update
                     PUT    /clientes/:id(.:format)                               clientes#update
                     DELETE /clientes/:id(.:format)                               clientes#destroy
            projects POST   /projects(.:format)                                   projects#create
         new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                               projects#new
```

Then, instead of:

```
<%= link_to "Nuevo Projecto", new_cliente_project_path() %>
```

You'll need to do something like:

```
<%= link_to "Nuevo Projecto", new_project_path %>
```

On your new project form, you will need a clients select or something like that, so when you submit your form you will have the `client_id` available for creating the association.